# How do I test that the page has reloaded when I click a link to the current page?

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, spock, geb

I have a strange bug I'm trying to re-create with a test. I know what's causing the bug and how to fix it, but I can't figure out how to test it properly.

Scenario:

- My browser is on http://example.com/foo
- I click a link on that page with href="/foo" (the same page)
- The browser should reload the same page

I tried:

```
class SamePageHyperlinkSpec extends StatelessUserWebGebSpec {

    def 'users is on Foo page and clicks foo link'() {

        when:
            to FooPage

        then:
            // navigation.foo is a property in a super class that references
            // a particular navigation item
            navigation.foo.click()

        and:
            at FooPage
    }
}
```

...but that gave a false positive because although the browser didn't reload the page, it was already on that page. So, I figured I'd take a look at the PageChangeListener which should allow me to pass/fail on page change:

```
class SamePageHyperlinkSpec extends StatelessUserWebGebSpec {

    def 'users is on Foo page and clicks foo link'() {

        given:
            def listener = new MyPageChangeListener()
            browser.registerPageChangeListener(listener)

        when:
            to FooPage
        and:
            listener.changeCount = 0

        then:
            // navigation.foo is a property in a super class that references
            // a particular navigation item
            navigation.foo.click()

        and:
            at FooPage

        and:
            listener.changeCount == 1
    }
}

class MyPageChangeListener implements PageChangeListener {

    int changeCount = 0

    void pageWillChange(Browser browser, Page oldPage, Page newPage) {
        println "browser '$browser' changing page from '$oldPage' to '$newPage'"
        changeCount++
    }
}
```

...that fails (as it should) when there is no page reload, however it also fails when there is a page reload, because the page it ends up on is the same, ergo no page *change* happened.

I also tried duplicating the Page class (and it's "at" closure), however that always passed regardless of whether there was a page reload or not.

So, how do I test that the page has reloaded when I click a link to the current page?

Comment: Is there anything that changes about the page on reload? e.g. fields or elements visible etc?

Comment: @PaulHarris Nope, nada

Comment: Im trying to think of something other than this, but it would work.... basically you could use could cast your driver to a JavascriptExecutor then execute some Javascript that would add an element to the page. You can then reload and you will know it is done because the element you just added will have disappeared. There has to be a better way but my mind is being strangely idiotic currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @PaulHarris' lead, the JS approach seems to do the trick:

```
class SamePageHyperlinkSpec extends StatelessUserWebGebSpec {

    def 'users is on Foo page and clicks foo link'() {

        when:
            to FooPage

        and:
            browser.js.exec '$(document.body).attr("data-not-reloaded",true);'

        then:
            // navigation.foo is a property in a super class that references
            // a particular navigation item
            navigation.foo.click()

        and:
            at FooPage

        and:
            browser.js.exec 'return $(document.body).attr("data-not-reloaded") === undefined';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://automationoverflow.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/waiting-for-page-load-to-complete/) is a better and tested version of WaitForPageLoad implementation in C#.Net

```
public void WaitForPageLoad(int maxWaitTimeInSeconds) {
string state = string.Empty;
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxWaitTimeInSeconds));

    //Checks every 500 ms whether predicate returns true if returns exit otherwise keep trying till it returns ture
    wait.Until(d = > {

        try {
            state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
        } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
            //Ignore
        } catch (NoSuchWindowException) {
            //when popup is closed, switch to last windows
            _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.Last());
        }
        //In IE7 there are chances we may get state as loaded instead of complete
        return (state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    });
} catch (TimeoutException) {
    //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
    if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        throw;
} catch (NullReferenceException) {
    //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
    if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        throw;
} catch (WebDriverException) {
    if (_driver.WindowHandles.Count == 1) {
        _driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles[0]);
    }
    state = ((IJavaScriptExecutor) _driver).ExecuteScript(@"return document.readyState").ToString();
    if (!(state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
        throw;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you write down some value in a text field of the page,make a wait routine that waits for this text field to not be included on the page and after that you click the link?
So the procedure would be this:

1.- Write some new value in a text field or add a new html tag or something using js.

2.- Make a routine to wait until the element/value that you added to the page is not included on the page.

3.- Click the link.

4.- Call the waiting code.

Let me know if this works for you.